# Objective-C function pointer block property

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, function-pointers, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to implement something similar to the C# delegate concept in Objective-C.  I assumed it could be done, but I'm struggling to make it work.  I've set up a type def for my block:

```
typedef BOOL (^CompareBlock)(id obj1, id obj2);
```

I also have a property of a class for the block:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) CompareBlock compareBlock;
```

What I want to do is set the property in the `init` method with a reference to a preexisting method:

```
BOOL isGreaterThan(id obj1, id obj2)
{
     // perform some comparison

     return false;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
        self.compareBlock = isGreaterThan;

    return self;
}
```

I know this isn't the right syntax, but I can't figure out how this concept could be achieved.  I've tried casting the function to the block typedef that I defined, but an error says that that isn't allowed with ARC.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your `compareBlock` property is a block, and `isGreaterThan` is a function pointer.  These aren't interchangeable like this.  What you want is to do this:

```
self.compareBlock = ^(id lhs, id rhs){ 
    /* compare here */
    return (BOOL)comparisonResult;
};
```

Blocks let you state your comparator in the body of the method instead of in a named function.  If you wanted to actually use your `isGreaterThan` function, you'd just wrap it in a block, thus:

```
self.compareBlock = ^(id lhs, id rhs){ 
    return isGreaterThan(lhs,rhs);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve what I was trying to do using what iluvcapra suggested.  The main reason I was trying to do things the way I was before is for the sake of neatness.  I think this method achieves that:

```
+ (CompareBlock) isGreaterThan
{
     return ^(id object1, id object2)
     {
         // perform some comparison

         return compareResult;
     }
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
        self.compareBlock = [MyClass isGreaterThan];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend making isGreaterThan a class method, that way you won't get careless and accidentally stick an ivar in the comparison proc one day.

Comment: Actually, that's what I did in my REAL implementation.  I just recreated the scenario using an example here :P